# Como retirar o último caractere do último valor de uma array

Tags: php, array

Galera tenho o seguinte foreach:

```
$items = "";
foreach ($_POST['termos'] as $item) {
  if(isset($item)){
          $items = $items . $item . '+';
  }
}
```

Ele me retorna:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 1-valor+ 
[1] => 2-valor+ 
[2] => 3-valor+
 )
```

Pergunta: Como **SEMPRE** retirar o **último caractere** do último valor dessa array, no caso o `+` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php):

```
$items = [];
foreach ($_POST['termos'] as $item) {
  if(isset($item)){
      array_push($items, $item);
  }
}

$string = implode('+', $items);
echo $string; // residencial+mecanico+display+led
```

Demonstração no <kbd>[**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/C7nMBD)</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Pode combinar [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) para obter o último elemento do array e [subtstr](http://php.net/substr) para remover o último caracter do array:

```
<?php
$arr = array('1-valor+','2-valor+','3-valor+');
$ultimo = count($arr) - 1; //3 elementos
$arr[$ultimo] = substr($arr[$ultimo],0, -1); //remove o último caracter

echo $arr[$ultimo];
```

Comment: Vale comentar que só funciona com arrays numéricos.

Answer (score 2):

Usando as funções [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) e funções [`end`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.end.php) e [`key`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.key.php)

```
<?php 

end($items);
$key = key($items);

$items[$key] = substr($items[$key], 0, -1);
```

Nesse caso funciona com arrays associativos (sem índice numérico).